# RestKit 0.20 Add custom SSL-Certificate

Tags: restkit-0.20

In RestKit 0.10.x I could do something like this to add a SSL certificate:

```
SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)certificate);
        if( cert != NULL ) {

            [[RKClient sharedClient] addRootCertificate:cert];
            CFRelease(cert);
            [self trustCert:certificate];
            return YES;
        }
```

How do I solve it in RestKit 0.20.3?

Answer (score 0):

RestKit 0.2 uses AFNetworking to manage the underlying comma so that's where you need to set this information. Take a look at [these AFNetworking tests](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/9a40c0dc0f27e9a547fb173a0b1b5a06072e91f9/Tests/Tests/1.0%20Tests/AFURLConnectionOperationTests.m) related to certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. AFNetworking loads my certificate, but the request fails, without a specific error message (restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:576 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)")

Comment: How do you know that the certificate is loaded?